# why for_each works without std:: prefix

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11

What i think is that for_each is defined in standard namespace, but this code actually compiles and runs with the following compiler flags. Can somebody please explain why?

```
  //@filename myprog.cpp 
  //g++-4.5 --std=c++0x myprog.cpp

  #include<iostream>
  #include<algorithm>

  int main()
  {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout<<"printing the number\n";
    for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int num) {//no std::for_each
        std::cout<<num<<"\t";
    });
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: lookup ADL - there are lots of questions on this site (Argument Dependent Lookup)

Comment: I'm thinking this won't be portable.  I know you're just curious, but I suggest using `std::` to be safe.

Comment: Compiles and runs on which compiler and standard library implementation?

Comment: @Nicol: Does `g++-4.5 --std=c++0x myprog.cpp` answer your question?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham , yes i'm curious. In my project i missed `std::` at a few places before for_each, and today i saw those mistakes. But the program is running correctly for so long!. This is no good.

Comment: @Nim: Your comment should have been an answer.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: I agree. Anyways, thanks Nim for the answer

Comment: @Merlyn: It's perfectly portable (works exactly as defined in the specification), but it will only work as long as either the iterators or the function are in `std::`, so for your own collections, you have to write `std::`.

Comment: @Jan I don't think there's anything in the standard requiring `vector<T>::iterator` to be a member of `namespace std` (indeed, it could just be a typedef for `T*`), so it's safest to use `std::` even for the standard collections.

Comment: @Jan: Good info.  Thx :)

Comment: @Jan, converted to answer... didn't think it was worth it initially...

Comment: @Alan: You are right. 3.4.2.2 says "Typedef names and using-declarations used to specify the types do not contribute to this set." and the actual iterator type does not necessarily have to be in `std::`.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: generally they are, *All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace
std or namespaces nested within namespace std.* So unless the iterators are pointers instead of classes, which none of the modern implementations does, the ADL will find the functions in std namespace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Converting comment to answer, the reason this works is ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup). Basically what this means is that on failing to find a suitable match for `for_each` in the current namespace, the compiler has a built-in rule which says, now look in other namespaces - and the set of namespaces it uses for this are the namespaces of the arguments. Once it has a set of namespaces, it will search through them to find a suitable `for_each`.

The question that remains open is whether `std::vector<>::iterator` resides in `std::` or not. Clearly in your implementation it does, which is why the appropriate `for_each` in `std::` is found. There *may be* cases where this iterator is not in `std::` - so to be safe (as in Alan's comment), always get into the habit of qualifying with `std::`.

Also this prevents any cases where someone else introduces another `for_each` (for arguments sake) in to your namespace - which may break things (in a worse case scenario - silently accepts - but breaks at run time).

Comment: +1 because I've discovered it only some weeks ago and it still amaze me; an addition : One of the reasons for such features is allowing free-function operators to work without having to specify any namespace.

Comment: "failing to find a suitable match in the default namespace"? I don't think ADL works like that. You'd have problems with overloading across namespaces if the "default namespace" would hide the associated namespaces. What's the default namespace anyway? Did you mean the current?

Comment: @MSalters, sorry I meant that in the context of the OP's situation.. I'll change it..

Comment: @MSalters: If I read the specification correctly, the default namespace indeed does not hide the argument-dependent ones, but if there is an overload in default namespace that ends up being better match, you still get silent change of meaning.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: Sounds like a correct one-line summary. But a "change of meaning" depends on what you expect. Remember, ADL applies only to unqualified "just give me the best match" calls. If you expect `::Foo::Bar()`, then call `::Foo::Bar()`.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: but that's exactly what you want with unqualified call, just as always, you want the best overload. So what's the problem? I'd say use qualified and unqualified calls as appropriate, rather then "always get into a habit" of using whatever.

Comment: @Gene, that implies you have knowledge of all overloads, which you may not, and what the compiler thinks is the best match based on arguments only may not be what you need?

Comment: @Nim: again, just with regular functions, you provide overloads intentionally, not randomly :-)